# ImportError: No module named app.update_handler

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app.update_handler import get_updates
ImportError: No module named app.update_handler
```

How can fix? I have this problem

Comment: Could you give a bit more details? Where is located app? and how does app look like?

Comment: https://github.com/d-Rickyy-b/Meet-n-Bot

Comment: i put this on my local home

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a directory structure:
   `app/update_handler.py`
and get_updates inside `update_handler.py` file

In case yes, then you need to add `__init__.py` file inside app directory as well.

Comment: and that I write to you in the init file?

Comment: Adding blank __init__.py  file inside app directory will work!!